# Pandas dataframe: create new column using conditional and slicing string

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this piece of code that creates a new dataframe column, using first a conditional, and then slicing some string, with a fixed slicing index (0, 5):

```
df.loc[df['operation'] == 'dividend', ['order_adj']] = df['comment'].str.slice(0, 5)
```

But, instead of having a fixed slicing index, I need to use `str.find()` at the final of this code, to have a dynamic slice index on `df['comment']`, based on its characters.

As I'm creating a new column by broadcasting, I couldn't find the correct sintaxe to use `str.find('some_string')` `inside str.slice()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Option using [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings):

```
df['comment'].str.split("some_string").str[0]
```

Or option using regex (move the capture group to be where you want regarding inclusive/exclusive):

```
pandas.Series.str.extract("(.*?)some_string")
pandas.Series.str.extract("(.*?some_string)")
```

Comment: Please note that I'm broadcasting an entire column based on a condition. str.split() works but the result is not what I need, because it considers df['comment'] as a series.

Comment: I'm don't understand what you mean then. Are you trying to slice each item within `df["comment"]` or slice the entire column of `df["comment"]`? Basically do you want the first n characters of each string for each row, or do you just want the first n rows as is.

Comment: If you provide an example in/out in your question it would make it much more clear

Comment: I need to slice each item of `df['comment']` in the same line of this conditional, if the condition is true. When I apply `df['comment'].str.split("some_string").str[0]`, for some reason it is slicing the string considering the first row of `df['comment']`. I guess it considers this column as a series and slice just the first row.